# How do I export site security groups and memberships with PowerShell?

Tags: 2010, powershell, security, groups, third-party-software

I'm looking for a PowerShell script (or tool) to export a site's groups and group memberships to a text file.

These files would be used as backup for the current security configuration in case the settings were accidently mucked up, as well as for auditing misconfigured sites (e.g. only one site owner, public access granted inappropriately, etc.).

Does anyone know of any existing scripts to accomplish this task?

Are there any third party tools that can accomplish the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine wrote a huge powershell script to do a lot of different functions around security. He has posted it to his blog here: http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/04/24/the-power-of-powershell-and-sharepoint-enumerating-sharepoint-permissions-and.aspx. If you look around line 73 you should see the part of the script that you are looking for to be able to enumerate SharePoint group members. Once you have this working, you can just pipe the results to a text file.